# Using a single shared element across multiple partial views

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have a basic ASP.Net MVC 3 application which has a number of controllers and a number of actions (and subsequently views)

A common feature of the application is to show a pop-up dialog window for basic user input. One of the key features of this dialog process is a faded mask that gets shown behind the dialog box.

Each of these dialog window controls is in a separate Partial View page.

Now, some view pages may use multiple dialog boxes, and therefore include multiple partial views in them - which as is would mean multiple instances of the "mask" element.

What I am trying to find a solution for is to only need to create one instance of a "mask" element regardless of the number of dialog partial views I include, and then the script in each partial dialog will have access to this element (so basically it just needs to be on the page somewhere)

The only real idea I have come up with so far is to add the "mask" element to the master page (or in the original view page) and this will mean it only gets added once. The problem here is that it will be added even when it is not needed (albeit one small single element)

I can live with this, but I would like to know if there is a better way to handle these kinds of scenarios?

A quick idea that came to mind is some kind of master page inheritance hierarchy, So I may have a DialogMasterPage that inherits from the standard current master page. How does that sound for an approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do something like this, where each module can register their need for a certain thing in the master page, you can use `HttpContext` to store a flag of whether you need to write the mask div, and just set that property in each partial.  At the end of the master page, if the flag is set, you can then write the mask div if its set to `true`.

Obviously to make this cleaner you could wrap it all in an `HtmlHelper` extension or something.

Comment: Good answer, will probably use this. Hold out for the bounty, I will award in a couple of days if nobody else comes up with anything better.

Comment: Thanks, I've used this same method before for partials to register their needs for certain javascript libraries, so I don't write out includes multiple times, I think similar principle applies here.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is for you to use something like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) where it handles the masking for you or if you are using something custom you can load the content for the dialog via ajax then show it in the single dialog on the master page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using JQuery for the showing and processing of the dialog but I never got on with JQuery UI dialogs when I first used them so would prefer to keep it my own custom way. I suppose I could create and dispose of the "mask" element from javascript with each "show dialog" call. I could then include a common javascript library for my partial views to handle this.